# RSelenium with chromedriver 2.20 on Ubuntu 14.04 webdriver exception

Tags: r, selenium-chromedriver, rselenium

I have installed chromedriver on  my linux server and its running

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.20.353124 (035346203162d32c80f1dce587c8154a1efa0c3b) on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.
```

R throws an error:

```
> startServer(args = c("-port 4444"))
> remDr = remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4444, browserName = "chrome")
> remDr$open()
[1] "Connecting to remote server"
Error:   Summary: UnknownError
     Detail: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
     class: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException
```

Comment: do I need Xvfb :1 -screen 5 1024x768x8 & ???

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to manually call the Selenium server with DISPLAY parameter.

```
command <- "DISPLAY=:1 xvfb-run java -jar /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RSelenium/bin/selenium-server-standalone.jar &"
system(command, intern = FALSE)
```